# Force BuildWindowCore member of a HwndHost derived class to be called

Tags: wpf, visibility, hwndhost

I use a class derived from HwndHost to host a Win32 window. It is in turn used within a user control. That user control doesn't get shown (Visibility) unless the internal Win32 window gets successfully created. However, the BuildWindowCore method doesn't appear to be called unless the HwndHost window is visible, so I have a chicken & egg situation.

If a HwndHost derived class is not visible, is there another way to get it's BuildWindowCore method called?

Comment: Why do you want to create the Win32 Window first?  Are you expecting that process to fail somehow?

Comment: In short, yes, its creation can fail. In long, it has to do with our legacy code and how it functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a month has passed with no answers. Looks like I've stumped everyone including myself.

So, the answer as of .NET 4.0 is "No, there is no way to force BuildWindowCore to be called before the framework is ready to call it."

Answer (score 0):

You can create your Win32 window yourself and just use HwndHost as a wrapper like in the example below.

```
ref class MyHost : HwndHost 
{
private:
   HWND  m_hWnd;
public:
   MyHost(HWND hWnd)
   {
      m_hWnd = hWnd;
   }
protected: 
  virtual HandleRef BuildWindowCore(HandleRef hwndParent) override 
  {
     // Simply re-parent the window
     SetParent(m_hWnd, (HWND) hwndParent.Handle.ToPointer());
     return HandleRef(this, (IntPtr) m_hWnd);
  } 

  virtual void DestroyWindowCore(HandleRef hwnd) override
  {
     ::DestroyWindow(m_hWnd);
  }
};
```

Comment: That may actually work. I suddenly feel like a junior programmer this morning for not thinking of that myself. Thanks.

Comment: Now I remember why I couldn't do it this way. The unmanaged window creates other child windows and messages start flying around between them. I need to process some of these in MyHost. That's why I can't create the window until BuildWindowCore.

Comment: Although an old post I wanted to add a comment. When I tried the above I get a hang when I call BuildWindowCore. I suspect BuildWindowCore is called by the WPF message processing loop and BuildWindowCore somehow ends up waiting for the processing loop to process a message. However I am not at all certain of this, just wanted to let people who read this know that you may see the same